# over text mark another text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for js code (maybe jquery) that will mark some text when I overmouse on another text (they both will have the same ID)

I have number of URLs and I want that overmouse on them will change table cell color

for example:

overmouse on url1 will mark cell ID 20

overmouse on url2 will mark cell ID 18

Thanks

Comment: you cannot have multiple identical ID on the same page. Anyway, could you show your attempts?

Answer (score 0):

A more advanced solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ggDzw/4/

```
<table border="1">
    <tr> 
        <td id="cell20">CELL 20</td>
        <td id="cell201">CELL 201</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="cell300">CELL 300</td>
        <td id="cell301">CELL 301</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="cell18">CELL 18</td>
        <td id="cell181">CELL 181</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<h1>
<a id="url1" href="http://www.9gag.com/">URL 1</a><br>
<a id="url2" href="http://www.giorgiacosplay.com/">URL 2</a>
</h1>
​
function URLtoCellHighlight(urlID, cellID) {

$("#" + urlID).hover(

function() {
    $("#" + cellID).addClass("highlight")
}, function() {
    $("#" + cellID).removeClass("highlight")
        });
}

    URLtoCellHighlight("url1", "cell20");
    URLtoCellHighlight("url2", "cell18");
​
.highlight { background-color: yellow }
h1 { color: red }
​
```

Here's a basic example with SPANs

http://jsfiddle.net/ggDzw/

```
<span id="text1">TEXT 1</span>
<span id="text2">Other Text</span>
​
.highlight { background-color: yellow }​

$("#text2").hover(
function() {
    $("#text1").addClass("highlight")
}, function() {
    $("#text1").removeClass("highlight")
});​
```

Comment: Thanks
But if I have lots of URLS than I will need lots of script codes
Is it possible to send the ID value of the URL to the script?

Comment: In my solution, you have to call this function matching a URL to a table CELL. `URLtoCellHighlight("url1", "cell20");` If you really want to save typing use an object that does the association and call the function on the object elements. good luck

Comment: OK, thanks good, but can we not use the "URLtoCellHighlight("url1", "cell20");" part?  and just check if the cell id and url id are the same?

Comment: if I knew how I wouldn't ask for it :)

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 different id's for the text you want highlighted and the trigger text:

```
<span id="part1_text" class="class">my text</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed dapibus risus at est sollicitudin vulputate. Quisque tristique velit nec lorem consequat non placerat nibh iaculis.

<br /><br />

<span id="text">hover me</span>​
```

use `hover`:

```
$('#text').on('hover', function(){
    var nextId = '#part1_'+$(this).attr('id');
    $(nextId).toggleClass('class2');
});
​
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8FwSk/)

Comment: Thanks
But if I have lots of URLS than I will need lots of script codes
Is it possible to send the ID value of the URL to the script?